# ANTLR parsing big files

Tags: python-3.x, performance, antlr, antlr4

Im parsing C++ with Python3 using ANTLR. For a 10-20 line code it take around 25~30sec whic is already too much, but when i try to parse a C++ file with 2k line of code(one single line) then it goes longer than 1hour, which is far too much! I will have more than one file that big and waiting that long for parsing will make my tool unusable!

I have very basic code as below and in the visitor I have 3 visitor function.

```
    input_stream = FileStream(sys.argv[1])
    cpplex = CPP14Lexer(input_stream)

    commtokstream = CommonTokenStream(cpplex)

    cpparser = CPP14Parser(commtokstream)
    print(" parse errors: {}".format(cpparser._syntaxErrors))

    tree = cpparser.translationunit()

    tv = TREEVisitor()
    tv.visit(tree)
```

Is 1 hour is normal for 2k line of code? Is there anyway I can optimize this?

This is the grammar file im using https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/cpp/CPP14.g4

Comment: Without much information (what grammar you use, and the hardware specification) it is impossible to discuss further.

Comment: If you want high performance parsing then don't use a scripting language (even though Python can be compiled in some sense). Use C++ instead for best possible speed. Even the Java target is faster than Python (I don't have a link to support that claim, just remember execution times I have seen in the past, except for C++, which I tested personally).

Comment: The Java target is much, much faster. I work on a project where complex SQL queries are inspected, and ~2000-3000 LOC SQL files take on average more than 30 sec. to parse using the Python3 target, while the Java target takes less than 1 second (!). These are average times, calculated over many different large SQL file parses. Of course, that does not mean the Java target is 30 times faster: it's just the case in combination with the grammar I'm using. I've used different SQL grammars for the same flavour of SQL that differ greatly in parse times.

Comment: Yeah so big part of this is related to the grammar it self. Do you think if I use the same grammar but with Java or C++ target I might get better result?
I can code in C++ and Java but I don't know enough about ANTLR grammars to improve the current grammar for better performance.

Comment: I just tried to parse the same sample c++ file with C++ target and it took 2min!!!

Comment: Could you post the C++ source file that you're parsing, curious to see how much the Java runtime takes.

Comment: This is the code I used in my tests its 2465 LOC, https://github.com/google/re2/blob/master/re2/parse.cc

- Python3 : ~35min
- C++ : ~3min

Im also interested how java runtime will do.